# MySQL fields from different rows to one string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with data like this:

```
Id   sort     name
1      1       abc
1      2       kci
2      1       asd
2      2       eww
2      3       der
2      4       acu
3      1       awq
3      2       see
3      3       eee
```

is it possible to create query that will give me result

```
Id     ConcName
1      abc,kci
2      asd,eww,der,acu
3      awq,see,eee
```

Comment: Yep, via [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT  ID, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY sort ASC) ConcName
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83bf/3)
- [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`, GROUP_CONCAT(`name` ORDER BY `sort`)
FROM `myTable`
GROUP BY `Id`
```

Comment: backticks are unnecessary on this case since no column or table name is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I think they make query more readable.

Comment: *"..more readable."* -- I don't think so. I think you mean safer. `:)`

Comment: also, who memorizes the long list of reserved words. Read: are you 100% sure `NAME` and `SORT` are not reserved? My personal rule is: If in doubt, put backticks, they don't hurt.

Comment: @Hazzit are you talking to me? I'm 100% sore they aren't. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83bf/3

Comment: @JW. - I know they aren't, and I know where to check. All I'm trying to say is with the long list of existing reserved words it can be hard to tell at first glance. Adding backticks around words that *might* be a reserved words answers the question without having to look it up. I tend to put backticks around english words that *might* be reserved. They might not be necessary, but they also don't cost anything, like the `ASC` in your query.